# div inside another div not expanding to page height, only to screen height

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a container div that has the height of my body which is 100%

```
  #pageContainer{
   width:800px;
   margin:auto;
   height:inherit;
   }
```

inside it  i have second div positioned absolutely

```
  <div style="position:absolute;opacity:.05;background-color:white;width:inherit;height:100%;"></div>
```

So my page looks like this:

```
 <body>
 <div id="pageContainer">
 <div style="position:absolute;opacity:.05;background-color:white;width:inherit;height:100%;"></div>
 <div>some content here</div>

 </div>
 </body>
```

So the problem is the absolutely positioned div has height equal to the screen size, not the page, another words when page is heigher than the visible screen, when I scroll down the div is not expanding to the full height of the parent div (pageContainer). I have tried the top:0px;bottom:0px; as well and it doesn't work. Any one knows what's the trick here?

Comment: is it cutting off content? or is this a visual problem?

Comment: the absolutely positioned div is empty so there is no content cut off, the problem is it only takes the height of the visible screen, not the whole page

Comment: Is the absolutely positioned div just used for a single colour background? If so, use `position: fixed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript: You'd either use jQuery via .height() or [EqualHeight](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/),
or

CSS: you'd do something like this: [CSS equal columns](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `height` of each element in the hierarchy to make it expand like this.

Try something like:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Setting the height of the `html` element is the one that I generally forget to do.  It is usually also be necessary to set the `#pageContainer` height to `100%`, although you have it inheriting from the body, so in this case you're okay.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position:relative;` to your #pageContainer. Currently, the absolutely positioned div is taking it's position from the window and not the container div.